# EF6 code first update-database success then model changed error?

Tags: entity-framework

Getting a frustrating issue at the moment where I am geting the error, "The model backing the 'AscertusWebDbContext' context has changed since the database was created", even though I have just run update-database which appears to have completed successfully.

So, steps I reverted to:

```
1) Delete database from (localdb)\v11.0 instance
2) Run add-migration blah
3) Run update-database
4) Debug the web application
5) Get the error above
```

Now the only thing I can think is that something has changed in the Microsoft underlying 'Organisational' authentication classes because I moved the two tables Tenants and IssuingAuthorityKeys from the default context into the DAL dll that I use which has its own context.

So I created a new MVC project using the same Organisation Authentication and the new classes created were exactly the same as what I am using both tables just have a sing string Id field in them.

The last thing I tried was to rollback to a previous target migration, make a change and force a rescaffolding of the last migration I created. The migration history shows the migration applied, the change has been applied to the table but I still get the same error.

Any help appreciated, where do I start looking for this problem as I'm getting zero feedback from anywhere I can think of.

Thanks

Stu

Comment: first point, if you have 2 different projects one for the web and one for the DAL(EF)... be sure that the DAL project doesn't have any connection strings and that the web.config in the web project have the right connection string.

Comment: Yeah, I'm betting you're updating one database but trying to run the application against a second database.

Comment: Thanks, no the connection strings in the configs of both projects were pointing to the same database. Removed the entire <connectionstrings> tag from the EF project and same problem.

Comment: I can also see the changes have been made in the correct database that I am connection too and the migration history has been updated accordingly.

Comment: What about migration on the other context? http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/multi-tenant-migrations-with-entity-framework-6-0-code-firs/

Comment: Thanks Steve, that might be worth a try, will start looking into it.

Comment: It looks like the issue is/was to do with an AllowHTML attribute on one of the fields, the SQL was ignoring the MaxLength when this was applied so therefore seeing a varchar(max) in the database and a max length of 512 in the markup.